# Is it possible to save questions over different sites?

Tags: feature-request, saves

I have saved some questions on Stack Overflow, and I have just saved a question on [the DBA site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour).

It might be useful to have a list of all saved questions, without needing to surf to each individual Stack Exchange site.

Is this already possible and/or are there plans to implement this?